# Regex C# - match any YouTube.com URI

Tags: c#, regex, youtube

I need to check with C# if a given URI is a page of the YouTube site.

```
string theUri = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4N_CliHGUk&feature=player_embedded";
bool isYoutube = Regex.IsMatch(theUri.ToString(), @"/https?:\/\/(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be|youtube-nocookie\.com).*/i");
```

The regular expression is not complicated and it should work without problems:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be|youtube-nocookie\.com).+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0EjytNo70JQFniFn)

But it's not working; the `isYouTube` bool is false with a simple URI like this `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeC4NKDVl70&feature=player_embedded`

Where I'm wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var youtubeHosts=new string[]{"youtube","youtube-nocookie","youtu.be"};
Uri uri=new Uri(path);
bool isValid=youtubeHosts.Any(x=>uri.Host==x);
```

Comment: Working with these youtubeHosts: `var youtubeHosts = new string[] { "youtube.com", "www.youtube.com", "youtube-nocookie.com", "www.youtube-nocookie.com", "youtu.be", "www.youtu.be" };` thank :)